# Using Entity reference + Views to create members select list

Tags: views, nodes, organic-groups

How can  I use VIEWS + ENTITY REFERENCE to get list of active members specific to the CURRENT GROUP [created via organic groups].

I have created a view that list active members belonging to the group.

I have seen [Restricting selectable entities with Views](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/restricting-selectable-entities-with-views)

But my question is, that is it possible with entity reference too ?

If yes how can I achieve this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The view will need to know which group, which means a Context Filter.  So options there are usually the current url or the current signed in user.  Depending on where your entity reference is, and how you are getting to it, there might be a context available to fill your filter.  Then the view will be usable to limit the options in your reference field.  The more details you can provide about the use case, the better I can make this answer.